# Render distance in Processing P3D (Vertexes disappear)

Tags: 3d, processing

I have a 3D world with x,y,z coordinates where I can move around. However, when I move away from vertices (translate) they disappear. How can I change this?

I am using TRIANGLE_STRIP.

I am including below what I use to draw the vertices and connect them.

```
for (int y = 0; y < rows-1; y++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    fill(100, 40, 40);
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
        vertex(x*scl, y*scl, map[x][y]);
        vertex(x*scl, (y+1)*scl, map[x][y+1]);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

Here is an animation to better explain:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAVsc.jpg

Comment: I have no experience with it, but it seems the [frustum](https://processing.org/reference/frustum_.html) determines the max distance rendered.

Comment: @J.D Thanks for that, but unfortunately i have just tried [frustum()](https://processing.org/reference/frustum_.html)and [perspective()](https://processing.org/reference/perspective_.html). The **zFar** value does not affect my drawing in any way. The other parameters such as ratio and fov do affect the sketch. Is there an upper limit to zFar?

Comment: I found the source of the problem. using an image as background (stars in my case) causes render distance to decrease (maybe clipping with background image)